# How to turn on "File and Folder sharing with SMB" via script

Tags: python, applescript

In the company I work at we're trying to allow file sharing on all the mac's so me and my IT team are able to see their files remotely. But I'm not very familiar with macs. Is there a way to script this process, preferably in Python? (If not python, then applescript)

Comment: https://www.apple.com/remotedesktop/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Googling around, it seems to me that you can turn on SMB file sharing for a folder with this set of command lines, which you can run from Python or AppleScript as you see fit:

```
sudo /usr/sbin/sharing -a /path/to/sharedFolder
sudo /usr/sbin/sharing -e sharedFolder -s 001
sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.smbd.plist
```

The first line creates a sharing record, the second adds the SMB flag to the record, and the third starts the file server.

The [site where I saw the last command](https://lisowski-development.com/activating-file-sharing-via-terminal/) had a second command:

```
sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.smb.server.plist EnabledServices -array disk
```

I don't know what precisely this line does — if anything — though it may ensure that SMB is restarted after a reboot(?)

N.B.: I'm not sure when the *sharing* command line tool was added to the system. It may be recent, so if you are running older systems you should check to make sure it's available.  See [man sharing](https://ss64.com/osx/sharing.html) for examples and options.